# Remove multiple line breaks between string and replace with single line breaks in java

Tags: java, android, regex

I have string

```
String description = a 
\n
\n
\n
\n
\n
b
```

I want to remove the line break to be just 1 line break.
Remove more than 2 line break to be just 1 line break.

I have tried this

```
String descResult = description.replaceAll("([\n]){2,}", "");
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: You removed them. Replace with `\n` (or `$1` since you capture each `\n` into Group 1). Try just `.replaceAll("\n{2,}", "\n")`. Or, `.replaceAll("(\\R){2,}", "$1")` to replace with the last linebreak sequence captured.

Answer (score 1):

Try it, replacement must be `\n`

```
String descResult = description.replaceAll("([\n]){2,}", "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to new lines, you seem to be having surrounding spaces too, so you need to use a regex that optionally captures optional spaces too. Try this Java code,

```
String s = "a \n \n \n \n \n b";
System.out.println("Before: " + s);
System.out.println("After: " + s.replaceAll("( *\n *){2,}", "\n"));
```

Prints,

```
Before: a 




 b
After: a
b
```

Comment: There are no spaces in the real string, the question was not formatted well.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Yea you're right. While I was answering, the given string had spaces due to which I thought it won't work so posted my solution. But I think in general one may optionally have spaces with newlines and in that case my answer may help others too. Thanks for your message though.